# Discord.js - AFK Disappears After An Hour Or So

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have an AFK Command, it works completely fine. It sets the AFK, it reminds that the user is AFK when pinged & it removes the AFK when the user sends another message. BUT, there is a problem. For some reason, the bot removes the AFK after an hour or so. Just completely disappears: No reminders, no nothing, doesn't even remove the AFK!
I wanna know why this happens

```js
const db = require(`quick.db`)

if (db.has(message.author.id + '.afk')) {
  let currentNickname = message.member.displayName
  let newNickname = currentNickname.replace(`[AFK]`, ``);
  message.channel.send(`Welcome Back ${message.author}!`).then(message => {
    message.delete({ timeout: 15000 })
  })
  message.member.setNickname(newNickname).catch(error => false);
  db.delete(message.author.id + '.afk')
  db.delete(message.author.id + '.messageafk')
  db.delete(message.author.id + '.time')
}
if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('>afk')) {
  let reason = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')
  if(!reason) reason = `AFK`
  let nickname = message.member ? message.member.displayName : null;
  message.member.setNickname(`[AFK] ${nickname}`).catch(error => false);
  db.set(message.author.id + '.afk', 'true')
  db.set(message.author.id + '.messageafk', reason)
  db.set(message.author.id + '.time', Date.now())
  message.channel.send(`${message.author}, AFK Set: ${reason}`)
}
message.mentions.users.forEach(user => {
  let timestamp = db.get(user.id + '.time')
  let timeAgo = moment(timestamp).fromNow()
  if (db.has(user.id + '.afk')) message.channel.send(user.username + ` Is AFK: ` + db.get(user.id + '.messageafk') + `
        - ${timeAgo}`)
})
```

Comment: By "doesn't even remove the AFK!", you are mean the [AFK] from the nickname, or the AFK role?

Comment: No! It's that the "Afk" just completely disappears after a few hours of afk being set. It should send a reminder that the user is afk when pinged, should remove "AFK" from the nickname if the user sends a message, should send a message saying it removed afk. But none of that happens, afk just completely disappears after the first few hours. And yes it does work completely fine on the first few mins